# Using LINQ to return an in int of how many Booleans are true within a List in a class

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to learn more about LINQ however I just cannot seem to figure it out, I'm attempting to count how many people are online in an object.

```
int amtOnline = 0;
int amtOffline = 0;
foreach(Row r in rowData.Rows)
{
    foreach(Profile p in r.Profiles)
    {
        if (p.IsOnline) amtOnline++; else amtOffline++;
    }
}
```

is what I'm currently using, but I'd like to use LINQ instead of a bunch of for each statements

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer the approach with loops as more straightforward but with LINQ one way is to flatten the nested collection and use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0) (and [`Convert.ToInt32(Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0#system-convert-toint32(system-boolean))):

```cs
var (amtOnline, amtOffline) = rowData.Rows
    .SelectMany(r => r.Profiles) // flatten the profiles
    .Aggregate(
        (amtOnline: 0, amtOffline: 0), // initial aggregation state using value tuple
        (agg, curr) => (agg.amtOnline + Convert.ToInt32(curr.IsOnline), agg.amtOffline + Convert.ToInt32(!curr.IsOnline))); // aggregate
```

Another approach is to use `GroupBy` on the flattened data:

```cs
var groupsDict = rowData.Rows
    .SelectMany(r => r.Profiles) // flatten the profiles
    .GroupBy(c => c.IsOnline)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var amtOnline = groupsDict.GetValueOrDefault(true);
var amtOffline = groupsDict.GetValueOrDefault(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get a single collection of Profile using `SelectMany`, which merges multiple collections into a single collection.

Then use `Count` to get the count of online profiles.

```
var onlineCount = rows
    .SelectMany(row => row.Profiles)
    .Count(profile => profile.IsOnline);
```